# Access Functions and controls on a Silverlight Page

Tags: silverlight

I am kind of new to Silverlight and I am having some issues. I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours now...

I have a main page that waits for a packet from a server. When that packet arrives it is handled in a module. Depending on the packet data the module handles an action. Some of those actions involve subroutines on the main page. I access them via:

```
Dim MainPage As MainPage = App.Current.RootVisual
If strPacketData(1) = "0" Then
MainPage.Do_Sign_In(True, strPacketData(2))
Else
MainPage.Do_Sign_In(False, strPacketData(2))
End If
```

And this works fine.

Assuming the sign in works the main page calls

```
Me.Content = New Page2
```

And the page switches to Page2

The problem is that the same code doesn't work when trying to access subs and controls on page2.

If I try:

```
Dim Page2 As Page2 = App.Current.RootVisual
If strPacketData(1) = "1" Then
Page2.lblCreateError.Opacity = 100
End If
```

I get Unable to cast object of type 'SLClient.MainPage' to type 'SLClient.Page2'.

What I am getting from this is that App.Current.RootVisual is set to MainPage, but MainPage shouldn't be open...

I have tried setting App.Current.RootVisual to Page2 but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I am hoping that this issue is caused by my ignorance of silverlight and that there is an easy fix for this...

I guess what I need to do is detect which page is currently being displayed and manipulate the controls and functions\subroutines on that page.

Any Input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know you found a work-around already but your RootVisual is your MainPage and in it, you have a content frame (navigation control) which you show Page2 in, correct? If so, MainPage will always be your RootVisual. What I do is in the `ContentFrame_Navigated` event, I save `e.content` to a public variable so I always know which page is currently shown.

Comment: Yeah I suppose that would have worked to. Silverlight is driving me nuts... I remember thinking how easy this was going to be... The server app! That is going to be the hard part! It has to manage all the connections and handle all the database commands and keep track of everything! but... no the server has been by far the easy part. All the client has to do is receive packets and display data. I never thought I would see the day when creating an asynchronous socket class turned out to be easier than displaying an image array. - Well sorry for the rant. Thanks for the response! -RW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well I finally figured it out. Or at least I figured out a way to do it.

I used a dictionary to store the addresses of the pages once they were created in memory. I also modified the program so that rootVisual is its own grid instead of a page. Now the grid loads and clears the pages as children.

I don't know... Silverlight is kind of screwy. Whatever, it works now.